# How can I add autocomplete functionality to an input field I've added in a .tpl template file?

Tags: forms, drupal, input, autocomplete

I have a custom module called "visionart cart" working as expected and have enabled a page through hook_menu();

```
 function visionart_cart_menu(){
     /**
     * Implements hook_menu()
     */
     $items['build-order'] = array (
            'title' => 'Build your order',
            'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
            'page callback' => 'visionart_cart_build_order',
            'access arguments' => array ('access content'),
            'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
          );
 }
```

Page callback returns the template page, everything works:

```
 function visionart_cart_build_order() {
   return theme('build_order_template');
 }

 /** Implements hook_theme. */
 function visionart_cart_theme() {
   return array (
     'build_order_template' => array (
       'template' => 'build_order'
     )
   );
 }
```

In build_order.tpl.php, I've added a bunch of custom HTML show up on the build_order.php page. Everything renders fine. But I'd like to add user autocomplete functionality to the input field that is created on this build_order.tpl.php file.

```
 <li class="my-custom-item">
      <input type="text" name="build_order_username" value="" />            
 </li>
```

How and where do I do that? I've seen how to create form fields programmatically through Drupal's form building functions, but i can't find where to indicate to Drupal that this custom created input should use autocomplete on the  user base. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will require an API endpoint call, which will auto-complete the fields. Assuming you are on Drupal 7, [here is a link](https://www.drupal.org/node/854216) from the official Drupal documentation on how to make autocomplete fields.